State not updating in combination of useEffect
I am making an chat application in that I want to fetch chats but this problem is coming. response.data is coming fine but state is not updating and null is printing for console.log("chats updated:", chats) after setting state.
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Chats() {
    const [chats, setChats] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const chload = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/getchats', {}, { withCredentials: true });
                if (response.data) {
                    console.log(response.data); 
                    setChats(response.data);
                    console.log("chats updated:", chats); 
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching chats:', error);
            }
        };
        chload();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {chats !== null ? (
                <>
                    <p>{chats.name}</p>
                </>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading chats...</p> 
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default Chats;


When you use useState, don't assume that the state will be updated immediately. React batches state updates and triggers a re-render after the component has been rendered. The updated state will be visible only after the component re-renders, which typically happens after the function inside useEffect .
In other words, state updates are asynchronous, and the new state value won't be immediately available right after calling setState. You need to rely on the component's next render cycle to access the updated state.
check this one setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

yah actually in nothing will be logged but the state was updated and i can acess it
